# Javascript convert vw to vh

Tags: javascript, css

I have a bunch of divs and I want to push down some of them with an offset. I do this by increasing their css 'top' property ( which is in vh ). The thing is that I have calculated that I have to increase the 'top' with some number of vw ( that is the screen width ). How can I convert this number to the screen height and then add it ( because I cannot write top: 5vh + 5vw, for example )

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can write

```
top: calc(5vh + 5vw);
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/calc